# Get only value from span (ASP.NET MVC)

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have code in View like this

```
<td class="FIO" style="text-align: center; font-size: 16px;">
    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FIO)
    @Html.Hidden("clientEmail", item.FIO)
</td>
```

Via JS I get value like this

```
<script>
  $(document).on('click','.FIO', function() {
        var FIO = $(this).text();
        alert(FIO);
  });
</script>
```

But I get this

> ```
>       "\n                Сухомлин Евгений\n                \n            "    object {string}
> ```

How I can get only

> Сухомлин Евгений

That's what coming in item.FIO
[image]

Thank's for help

Comment: can you show what is coming in item.FIO

Comment: Updated my post @Rush.2707

Comment: `var FIO = $(this).find('#clientEmail').text();` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use like below

```
    <td class="FIO" style="text-align: center; font-size: 16px;">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FIO)</td>
@Html.Hidden("clientEmail", item.FIO)
```

there is two new line included that is why \n is getting. Also put hidden field out of the td or some other td.

Comment: If the hidden field references data only relevant to that `td` it should stay in it if it is needed. You can simply update your JavaScript to look for the hidden field instead of trying to massage the DOM to suit the results. `@Html.Hidden("clientEmail", item.FIO)` should generate an element with the id `clientEmail` so something similar to `var FIO = $(this).find('#clientEmail').text();` should work - In the long run the hidden field will always contain the value, while the text you display could change based on requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like working great in here ....

```js
$(document).on('click','.FIO', function() {
        var FIO = $(this).text();
        alert(FIO);
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="FIO" style="text-align: center; font-size: 16px;">
    Сухомлин Евгений
    <input type="hidden" value="Сухомлин Евгений">
</div>
```